# How to server static file in slim framework without any extra middleware

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, routes, slim

Went through slim documentation and not able to find how to load css and js files.

URL routing is happening for css and js also and its not going to template folder

```js
$app = new \Slim\Slim([
        'debug' => true,
        'templates.path' => 'templates/'
    ]);
```

Comment: What is your precise question?

Comment: Webserver serves the static files. Slim receives the request only if the requested file is not found. This is done by the rewrite rules in .htaccess file.

Comment: @MikaTuupola that is very inaccurate. Slim is independent of the http server, the http server can be configured as you suggested, but it can be configured to ignore static files.
Additionally, the public directory might even not contain any static files at all.
What you described is a very wild assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case that configuring the webserver to serve these files is not an option (e.g. when the asset is selected dynamically), there is a bit of support in Slim:

```php
$app->get('/favicon.ico', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $streamFactory = new Slim\Psr7\Factory\StreamFactory();
    return $response->withBody(
        $streamFactory->createStreamFromFile(__DIR__ . '/favicon.ico')
    );
});
```

This code is specifically coded against Slim's PSR7 package. A more general approach would be to retrieve `Psr\Http\Message\StreamFactoryInterface` from the dependency injection (DI) container.

Answer (score 2):

Like Mika Tuupola commented, if a file exists on your webserver it get's served directly.

Just in case, this is how the default `.htaccess` file should look like:

```
  RewriteEngine On

  # Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
  # If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
  # absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
  #
  # RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If you are using nginx, then your `nginx.conf` should consist something like this:

```
  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }
```

Your project structure could look like this:

```
  /
  |->.htaccess
  |->index.php
  |->templates/
  |->css/
  |->js/
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the actual question. I have to point this out, as i am working with slim in a docker container without any web server. Thus any static files has to be handled by the application.